# Trying to get start and end time in hours from a set of 30 minute time intervals and some results aren't returning correctly

Tags: postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I'm trying to get a report of the hours worked out of a Postgresql database.  I'm going to use Python and Pandas to format run additional calculations before outputting to reports and I'm using the `pd.read_sqq_query()` method to pull the data into python using raw SQL.

The information is over multiple tables `users, intervals, claimed`. `Claimed` is a many to many mapping to `intervals` and to `users`.  I'm expecting to get multiple users back so I'm using the `PARTITION BY username` clause to group them. Please let me know if the layout might be causing the problem as my example below has been simplified some.

I've recently discovered various resources talking about gaps and islands problems and found one that seems to fit my use case that I've adapted to work; ***Ref: [Gaps and islands](https://bertwagner.com/2019/03/12/gaps-and-islands/)***.  It appears to be MSSQL though I don't believe it's mentioned in there.

### The problem is that some of the results aren't returning what I expect. I've created a SQL Fiddle with a minimum viable [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/1c254/1)

This is one of the segments found by the islands.  I'm taking the MAX(endtime) and the MIN(starttime) but in some cases I am missing the final interval.

Ex: The following table has one segment and I would expect it to show starttime as `2020-03-08T0:00:00` and endtime as `2020-03-08T4:00:00` but I'm actually getting the endtime as `2020-03-08T3:30:00`

```
╔═════════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║  Username   ║     Start Time      ║      End Time       ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ Test User 1 ║ 2020-03-08T02:00:00 ║ 2020-03-08T02:30:00 ║
║ Test User 1 ║ 2020-03-08T02:30:00 ║ 2020-03-08T03:00:00 ║
║ Test User 1 ║ 2020-03-08T03:00:00 ║ 2020-03-08T03:30:00 ║
║ Test User 1 ║ 2020-03-08T03:30:00 ║ 2020-03-08T04:00:00 ║
╚═════════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

This is what I have in the SQLFiddle for the example and there's more data but all for one user.

```sql
SELECT username,
       islandId,
       MIN(starttime) as IslandStartDate,
       MAX(endtime) as IslandEndDate
FROM
        (SELECT *,
                CASE
                    WHEN Groups.PreviousEndDate >= starttime THEN 0
                    ELSE 1
                END as IslandStartInd,
                SUM(CASE
                        WHEN Groups.PreviousEndDate >= starttime then 0
                        else 1
                    end) OVER (PARTITION BY Groups.username
                               ORDER BY Groups.RN) as IslandId
         FROM
                 ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY tr.username
                                             order by tr.starttime,
                                                      tr.endtime) as rn ,
                                            tr.username ,
                                            tr.starttime ,
                                            tr.endtime ,
                                            LAG(tr.endtime, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY tr.username
                                                                     ORDER BY tr.starttime,
                                                                              tr.endtime) as PreviousEndDate
                  FROM timerange tr
                  WHERE tr.starttime BETWEEN '2020-03-01' AND '2020-03-20'
                  ORDER BY tr.username) Groups ) Islands
Group BY username,
         islandid
ORDER BY username,
         IslandStartDate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have restructured the gaps-and-islands approach using window functions and common table expressions to make it easier to follow.

You can uncomment the commented queries at the bottom (one at a time) to see how the strategy works step by step.

[The sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/1c254/20).

```
with gaps as (
  select *,
         case 
           when starttime = lag(endtime) over (partition by username 
                                                     order by starttime) then 0
           else 1
         end as gap_begin_row_marker
    from timerange
), grp_numbers as (
  select username, starttime, endtime,
         sum(gap_begin_row_marker) over (partition by username
                                             order by starttime) as grp_num
    from gaps
), collapsed_intervals as(
  select grp_num, username, min(starttime) as starttime, max(endtime) as endtime
    from grp_numbers
   group by grp_num, username
), summed_time as (
  select username, sum(endtime - starttime) as time_claimed
    from collapsed_intervals
   group by username
)
/* select * from gaps; */
/* select * from grp_numbers; */
/* select * from collapsed_intervals; */
select * from summed_time;
```

Comment: Hi @Mike Organek, thanks for taking the time to look at my question.  I did as you suggested and started uncommenting the lines but islanid 3 still has the same issue.  It's returning the end time as 3:30 instead of the expected 4 and this is what I'm trying to figure out.  Uncomment line 27 of your fiddler and look at grp_num 3 to see what I mean.

Comment: @ScriptingDad  You have a time travel problem in Group 3.  Shift starts at 0330 on 03/14 and ends at 0400 on 03/13.

Comment: you are absolutely correct....I have no idea how that got in there. Going to have to see if this shows up elsewhere and figure out how it go in there.  Thanks that's what I was searching for.

Comment: @ScriptingDad You may want to add a check constraint to your table to verify `starttime < endtime`

Comment: Looks like it might have been caused by how I'm converting the input time to UTC time. Time is generally entered in EST/EDT time and zoned to UTC.  Not sure why it's doing this but I know where to look now.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do not convert it yourself, let Postgres do it. Either change the data type from timestamp to timestamptz or change your query to specify  "AT TIMEZONE UTC". Also caution: Do not use timezone abbreviations  "EST/EDT" use the full name "US/Eastern". The full name automatically adjusts for daily light savings time, the abbreviations do not. For full list see view pg_catalog.pg_timezone_names.

Comment: @Belayer I'm paying for the sins of my inexperienced past and will have to figure out how to modify my code to do that now. Thanks for the tips though maybe before long I'll get postgres doing this lifting.

Comment: We all have to pay our dues, if we are lucky sometimes someone has already paid part for us. Good luck.